# How to use php rand fucuction to generate 2 sets of data that match

Tags: php

i need to know how i can have a array with the rand function show up lets say a email and a password in two different text areas how would i do this

this is what ive already tried but keeps giving me string number instead of detail

index.php:

```
include "details.php";
$gen=array_rand($test);
$stock=count($test);


<form method='post' action='free.php'>
        <b>Email:</b><textarea name="email"><?php echo "$gen";?></textarea><br>
        <b>Password:</b><textarea name="password"><?php echo "$gen";?></textarea>
        <center>
            <button type="submit">Generate</button><br>
            stock:<?php echo "$stock";?>
        </center>
</form>
```

details.php

```
$test = [
['account' => 'acc1','pass' => 'pass1'],
['account' => 'acc2', 'pass' => 'pass2']
];
```

project link:
http://noxxeraltgen.tk/minecraft/free.php

Comment: *[`array_rand`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-rand.php) — Pick one or more random keys out of an array*. To get the coresponding value you'd need to do `$test[$gen]`

Comment: apokryfos im confused can you explain it a bit more\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`array_rand()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-rand.php) returns an index and not the actual array element.  From the manual...

> **Return Values**
>
> When picking only one entry, array_rand() returns the
>   key for a random entry. Otherwise, an array of keys for the random
>   entries is returned. This is done so that random keys can be picked
>   from the array as well as random values. Trying to pick more elements
>   than there are in the array will result in an E_WARNING level error,
>   and NULL will be returned.

You also need to specify the part of the array you want to output for each item,  so...

```
echo "$gen";
```

Should be either

```
<?php echo $test[$gen]['account'];?>
```

or

```
<?php echo $test[$gen]['pass'];?>
```